# PHPUnit gets segmentation fault

Tags: php, phpunit

Trying to get started using phpunit and can't get it installed/setup properly.  When I run it command line I get a segmentation fault.

```
Environment:
OSX 10.6.4
PHP 5.3.2 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2010 00:04:41) 
About pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.4.9
```

I tried disabling xdebug in php.ini and still got the error - the only difference was it wasn't appearing in the crash report. I had a macports install of php, I removed that.  I also removed phpunit and reinstalled it.  Here are the details:

```
Process:         php [13366]
Path:            /usr/bin/php
Identifier:      php
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [12089]

Date/Time:       2010-10-04 09:40:08.035 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.4 (10F569)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000d, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   inclued.so                      0x0000000100bf3e44 inclued_op_ZEND_ADD_INTERFACE + 308
1   php                             0x000000010033c4bd ZEND_USER_OPCODE_SPEC_HANDLER + 29
2   php                             0x000000010033984d execute + 585
3   xdebug.so                       0x0000000100d05f11 xdebug_execute + 3079
4   php                             0x0000000100347cd6 ZEND_INCLUDE_OR_EVAL_SPEC_CONST_HANDLER + 922
5   php                             0x000000010033984d execute + 585
6   xdebug.so                       0x0000000100d05f11 xdebug_execute + 3079
7   php                             0x0000000100347cd6 ZEND_INCLUDE_OR_EVAL_SPEC_CONST_HANDLER + 922
8   php                             0x000000010033984d execute + 585
9   xdebug.so                       0x0000000100d05f11 xdebug_execute + 3079
10  php                             0x0000000100347cd6 ZEND_INCLUDE_OR_EVAL_SPEC_CONST_HANDLER + 922
11  php                             0x000000010033984d execute + 585
12  xdebug.so                       0x0000000100d05f11 xdebug_execute + 3079
13  php                             0x0000000100347cd6 ZEND_INCLUDE_OR_EVAL_SPEC_CONST_HANDLER + 922
14  php                             0x000000010033984d execute + 585
15  xdebug.so                       0x0000000100d05f11 xdebug_execute + 3079
16  php                             0x0000000100318558 zend_execute_scripts + 376
17  php                             0x00000001002caec5 php_execute_script + 732
18  php                             0x0000000100394b9c main + 3646
19  php                             0x0000000100001164 start + 52
```

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks
-Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit... inclued.so extension was causing the problem.

I reverted back to the original osx php.ini and things worked, so I went back to the problem version of php.ini, removed one thing at a time and inclued extension was the winner!

PHP and PHPUnit now behaves quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Clearing the watch expressions fixed my segmentation error. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Dead simple solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, please disable Xdebug to check whether it's the reason. If yes, upgrade to the latest Xdebug version.

Comment: I had disabled xdebug before.  The only difference was that it didn't appear in the dump - i still got the seg fault.