# PHPUnit Segmentation fault

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, phpunit

When a PHPUnit test fails normally on my dev box (Linux Mint), it causes a "Segmentation Fault" on my Continous Integration box (Centos). Both machines are running the same version of PHPUnit. My dev box is running PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9, and the CI is PHP 5.2.17. I'd rather leave upgrading the PHP as a last resort though.

As per this thread: [PHPUnit gets segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855912/phpunit-gets-segmentation-fault)
I have tried deactivating / reinstalling Xdebug. I don't have inclue.so installed.

On the CI box I currently only have two extensions active: dom from php-xml (required for phpunit) and memcache (required by my framework), all the others have been turned off.

Comment: Please show how you invoke PHPUnit. Have you tried process isolation?

Comment: @hakre - yes I have tried process isolation, all I got were errors back due to my framework not being instantiated properly. I am simply calling it from commandline: phpunit quiz_service_Test.php

Comment: Does it crash **every time** or only sometimes? Also: You don't use any 5.3 features at all (so the goal is to create 5.2 compatible software? -- Like @powtac said, more memory might always help :)

Comment: @powtac My memory_limit in php.ini has been set to 300M and I am only running the single offending test. Is there somewhere else I should look for memory settings?

Comment: So you can reduce the problem to a single testcase or are all testcases with this error?

Comment: @edorian - It crashes every time without fail. It should be 5.2 compatible - my live box is 5.2.

Comment: @hakre only some test cases have this problem. Specifically where it is trying to use a socket that failed in creation.

Comment: Try to set to something very high like 700M or 1.5G. The memory consumption for tests can be very high!

Comment: @powtac I set my memory to 1500M, but unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: Raising the memory limit to deal with segmentation faults sounds a bit like gambling to me. Even if you can prevent the segfault in testing, what about the live app? Can it, too?

Comment: Check the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597468/how-to-diagnose-these-php-code-coverage-segmentation-and-zend-mm-heap-corrupted

Comment: Just noting my workaround: I needed to run the tests fully rather than try to run the tests individually. After doing this, I could then run individually again...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Next to [what cweiske suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343978/367456), if upgrading PHP is not an option for you and you have problems to locate the source of the segfault, you can use a debugger to find out more.

You can launch gdb this way to debug a PHPUnit session:

```
gdb --args php /usr/bin/phpunit quiz_service_Test.php
```

Then type in `r` to run the program and/or set environment variables first.

```
set env MALLOC_CHECK_=3
r
```

You might also consider to install the debugging symbols for PHP on the system to get better results for debugging. gdb checks this on startup for you and leaves a notice how you can do so.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me narrow it down. The data we are getting back from a server is too large for pcre.

Comment: Okay. You can limit that so that the preg_... won't segfault but it won't execute then in full as well (normally returns NULL if failed). [See the ini settings for pcre](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php).

Comment: For me it was a _stack overflow_ ;) that wasn't logged by phpunit, just a segfault.

Answer (score 22):

I've had an issue with PHPUnit segfaulting and had trouble finding an answer, so hopefully this helps someone with the same issue later.

PHPUnit was segfaulting, but only:

- If there was an error (or more than one)
- After all tests had run but before the errors were printed

After a while I realized that it was due to failures on tests that used data providers, and specifically for data providers that passed objects with lots of recursive references. A bell finally went off and I did some digging: the problem is that when you're using data providers and a test fails, PHPUnit tries to create a string representation of the provided arguments for the failure description to tell you what failed, but this is problematic when one of the arguments has some infinite recursion. In fact, what PHPUnit does in `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::dataToString()` (around line 1612) is print out all the arguments provided by the data provider using `print_r`, which causes the segfault when PHP tries to create a string representation of the infinitely recursive object.

The solution I came to was:

1. Use a single base class for all my test classes (which fortunately I was already doing)
2. Override `dataToString()` in my test base class, to check for these kinds of objects in the data array (which is possible in my case because I know what these objects look like). If the object is present, I return some special value, if not I just pass it along to the parent method.

Comment: that actually helped a lot. One better way would be to create the data structure in the test itself and create only plain data in the dataprovider (that worked for me)

Answer (score 11):

I had similar problem and by disabling the garbge collactor in

> PHPStorm => Edit configuration => Interpreter option : -d
>   zend.enable_gc=0

Or if you are running your tests from the command line you may try adding :

> -d zend.enable_gc=0

Answer (score 7):

When you get a segfault, upgrade your PHP to the latest version. Not only the latest in your package manager, but the latest available on php.net. If it still segfaults, you are sure that the problem has not been fixed yet in PHP itself. Don't bother trying to get rid of a segfault in old version of PHP because it might have been fixed already in a newer one.

Next step is to locating the problem: Make your test smaller and smaller until you can't remove anything (but it still segfaults). If you have that, move the test into a standalone php script that segfaults. Now you have a test script for your bug in the PHP bug tracker.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38789046/246790 which helped me a lot:

You can use PHP function `gc_disable();`

I have placed it in my PHPUnit bootstrap code as well with `ini_set('memory_limit', -1);`

Comment: This seems more of a means of 'temporarily masking' the issue than really fixing it. i.e. you are turning off the mechanism that catches circular references, then removing the memory limiter that prevents PHP from gobbling up all of your RAM, which could destabilize other things, like the OS.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone comes across this in relation to PHPunit within Laravel

It took a while to figure out what the issue was. I was going over the differences between my current code and the previous revision and through some trial and error finally got there.

I had two different models that were both including each other with the `protected $with` override.

This must have been causing some kind of loop that phpunit could not deal with.

Hopefully someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could nail it down, that I tried to write a class variable which was not definied:

My class (it's a cakePHP-class) which caused segmentation fault:

```
class MyClass extends AppModel {

  protected $classVariableOne;

  public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

    $this->classVariableOne =& ClassRegistry::init('ClassVariableOne');

    // This line caused the segmentation fault as the variable doesn't exists
    $this->classVariableTwo =& ClassRegistry::init('ClassVariableTwo');

  }
}
```

I fixed it by adding the second variable:

```
class MyClass extends AppModel {

  protected $classVariableOne;
  protected $classVariableTwo; // Added this line

  public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

    $this->classVariableOne =& ClassRegistry::init('ClassVariableOne');
    $this->classVariableTwo =& ClassRegistry::init('ClassVariableTwo');

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Infinite recursion is normally what causes this issue for us. The symptoms of infinite recursion seem to be different when running code under phpunit, than they are when running it in other environments.

Answer (score 1):

Please update to the newest XDEBUG. Got the same error while using v3.1.5, and after upgrading to 3.1.6 eveything works.

Comment: with  Xdebug v3.1.6 still faced with Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same problem. I upgraded the PHPUnit to the 4.1 version (to run the tests) and it was able to show me the object, as pointed by Isaac.

So, if you get to this very same problem, upgrade to PHPUnit >= 4.1 and you'll be able to see the error instead of getting "Segmentation fault" message.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting a `Segmentation fault: 11` when running PHPUnit with Code coverage. After doing a stack trace of the segmentation fault, I found the following was causing the Segmentation fault error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000100b8421a in xdebug_path_info_get_path_for_level () from /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
```

I replaced my current `xdebug.so` in the path above with the latest version from the [Komodo Remote Debugging Package](http://code.activestate.com/komodo/remotedebugging/) the sub-folder of the corresponding downloaded package with the PHP version I have (which is 5.5 for me) and everything worked.

Comment: For me, updating XDEBUG in my docker build from 3.1.5 to 3.1.6 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed a similar issue for me (when the output of the `gdb` backtrace  included `libcurl.so` and `libcrypto.so`):

disable `/etc/php.d/pgsql.ini`:

```
; Enable pgsql extension module
; extension=pgsql.so
```

edit `/etc/php.d/curl.ini` to ensure that `pgsql.so` is included before curl:

```
; Enable curl extension module
extension=pgsql.so
extension=curl.so
curl.cainfo=/home/statcounter/include/config/cacert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have an object with property pointing to the same object, or other sort of pointer loops, you will have this message while running

```
serialize($object);
```

And if you are a Laravel user, and you are dealing with models. And if you think, you will never have this problem, because you avoiding pointer loops by using `$hidden` property on your models, please be advised, the `$hidden` property does not affect `serialize`, it only affects casting to `JSON` and `array`.

I had this problem, when I had a model saved into a property of a `Mailable` object.

fixed with

```
$this->model->refresh();
```

in a `__construct` method , just before the whole object is serialized.

Answer (score -3):

This related to code not extension. In my case i had these two files

1. **Test Case**
2. **Example Test**

In **Test Case** there is method called *createApplication*. Just leave it empty.

In **Example Test** you can create the method and fill with 
*$this->assertTrue(true)*

Above is basic setup hope you can extend the requirement as you need.