# php sftp seg fault

Tags: php, sftp, readdir

What i need to do if next code gives me seg fault ?

```
    $handle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp".'/usr/bin/');
    $file = readdir($handle);
    closedir($handle);
```

where $sftp is

```
    $this->_connection = ssh2_connect($this->_server, 22);
    if($this->_authType==ExportInterface::CONN_AUTH_KEY) {
        ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($this->_connection,$this->_user,$this->_key,$this->_privateKey);
    } else {
        ssh2_auth_password($this->_connection,$this->_user,$this->_password);
    }
    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($this->_connection);
```

Connect work well. and segfault is when only i use readdir function.

Comment: Can you isolate that in a test-script and run it through [gdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343674/phpunit-segmentation-fault/6344061#6344061)?

Comment: By a long way, the most common cause of segfaults in PHP in my experience is a recursive function that recurses indefinitely.

Comment: @DaveRandom That shouldn't happen with suhosin installed. But the other likely cause for a segfault is a rarely tested native module, like ... ssh/sftp ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A seg(mentation) fault is an internal error in php or the SSH/SFTP extension. You should [file a bug](https://bugs.php.net/report.php) against the extension in question.

Don't forget to include a [short, reproducible example](http://sscce.org/). Since this may be only reproducible with your specific combination of ssh client and server, you should reproduce the bug first in a brand-new VM and record every step you make, like this:

1. Install Ubuntu 11.04 amd64 in the VM
2. Install ssh with `$ sudo apt-get install ssh`
3. Configure ssh with ...
4. Install php with `$ sudo apt-get install php5-cli`
5. Copy the script [link to http://pastebin.com/ here] to the VM
6. Type `php ssh-segfault.php` and receive a segfault.

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering this old question due to high ranking on Google search. I was experiencing the same segmentation fault and the real solution wasn't here.

It turns out that since PHP 5.6, the behavior of the function `ssh2_sftp` changed and is now returning a resource that doesn't allow to be concatenated as a string to form filesystem paths.

So, once you have the return of the `ssh2_sftp`, you have first to pass it through `intval` in order to build the remote file path:

```
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($this->_connection);
$handle = opendir('ssh2.sftp://' . intval($sftp) . '/usr/bin/');
$file = readdir($handle);
closedir($handle);
```

You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it upgrading the ssh2 pecl packaage to version 0.11.3

```
sudo pecl install ssh2 channel://pecl.php.net/ssh2-0.11.3
```

It worked for me after some problems.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Not applicable to the OP's situation, but if you fail to call closedir explicitly on the handle created by opendir, you'll also get a segfault during PHP internal cleanup at script end.

Comment: This was what was wrong in my situation. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, though with some additional factors. I'll start with the solution: use absolute paths, rather than relative. And avoid the `~`.

As for my findings. Take this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$ssh = ssh2_connect('hostname.example.com');
$res = ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($ssh, 'user', '~/.ssh/various-keys/special-key_2015.pub', '~/.ssh/various-keys/special-key_2015');
unset($res); unset($ssh);

$ssh = ssh2_connect('hostname.example.com');
$res = ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($ssh, 'user', '~/.ssh/various-keys/special-key_2015.pub', '~/.ssh/various-keys/special-key_2015');
```

Results in an authentication error in the 2nd `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file` call. A bit strange to encounter, after two identical calls - but easy enough to analyze.

But having the rest of my application code around it would result in the segfault. Eventually I narrowed it down to that that including a file, that defines a function that uses the `__FILE__` constant changes the error to turn into a segmentation fault.

Even a file as simple as this:

```
<?php
function nothing() { 
    error_log(__FILE__);
}
```

I hope this helps somebody else at some point...

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers above suggests you need to cast the resource to an int `intval($sftp)` to avoid the segfault.

While I believe this used to be the case, this now appears to have inverted, at least on php 7.1.9 and casting to an int now causes the segfault, at least with `file_put_contents`:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$remoteFile = 'ssh2.sftp://' . intval($sftp) . '/var/file.text'
echo $remoteFile
file_put_contents($remoteFile, 'Content');
```

> ssh2.sftp://2675/var/file.text
>
> Segmentation Fault

Without a cast it works:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$remoteFile = 'ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . '/var/file.text'
echo $remoteFile
file_put_contents($remoteFile, 'Content');
```

> ssh2.sftp://Resource id #2675/var/file.text