# I've Segmentation fault error when I run phpunit test

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony5

I've a web project on Symfony 5.4 / PHP 8.1

I try wrote tests for my API (Api Platform 2.6.8) but. when I want to execute a request of type `POST` or `PUT` declared as in the `testCreate()` method in `RaceApiTest`, it will execute correctly without problem.

On the other hand, if I do as in `testPut()`, when I run the test, it will return the error `segmentation fault` without more information (nothing goes back in the logs)

What is all the more strange because on the method `testGetCollection()` and `testGet()` it does not pose any problem and everything works fine

What it gives in console:

```
www-data@5cd579b1818c:~/project/symfony$ bin/phpunit --debug --verbose tests/Http/Controller/Api/RaceApiTest.php --filter testGet
PHPUnit 9.5.11 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.1.2
Configuration: /var/www/project/symfony/phpunit.xml

Testing App\Tests\Http\Controller\Api\RaceApiTest
Test 'App\Tests\Http\Controller\Api\RaceApiTest::testGetCollection' started
Test 'App\Tests\Http\Controller\Api\RaceApiTest::testGetCollection' ended
Test 'App\Tests\Http\Controller\Api\RaceApiTest::testGet' started
Test 'App\Tests\Http\Controller\Api\RaceApiTest::testGet' ended


Time: 00:06.637, Memory: 64.50 MB

OK (2 tests, 8 assertions)
----
www-data@5cd579b1818c:~/project/symfony$ bin/phpunit --debug --verbose tests/Http/Controller/Api/RaceApiTest.php --filter testCreate
PHPUnit 9.5.11 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.1.2
Configuration: /var/www/project/symfony/phpunit.xml

Testing App\Tests\Http\Controller\Api\RaceApiTest
Test 'App\Tests\Http\Controller\Api\RaceApiTest::testCreate' started
Test 'App\Tests\Http\Controller\Api\RaceApiTest::testCreate' ended


Time: 00:04.979, Memory: 56.50 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
---
www-data@5cd579b1818c:~/project/symfony$ bin/phpunit --debug --verbose tests/Http/Controller/Api/RaceApiTest.php --filter testPut
PHPUnit 9.5.11 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.1.2
Configuration: /var/www/project/symfony/phpunit.xml

Testing App\Tests\Http\Controller\Api\RaceApiTest
Test 'App\Tests\Http\Controller\Api\RaceApiTest::testPut' started
Segmentation fault
```

My code :

```
<?php
// test/ApiTestCase.php
namespace App\Tests;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase as BaseApiTestCase;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\Client;


class ApiTestCase extends BaseApiTestCase
{
    /**
     * Description $client field
     *
     * @var Client $client
     */
    protected Client $client;

    /**
     * Description setUp function
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->client = static::createClient();
    }
```

```
<?php
// tests/Http/Controller/Api/RaceApiTest.php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Tests\Http\Controller\Api;

use App\Domain\Auth\Entity\User;
use App\Domain\Character\Entity\Race;
use App\Tests\ApiTestCase;
use App\Tests\FixturesTrait;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\ClientExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\DecodingExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\RedirectionExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\ServerExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\ResponseInterface;

class RaceApiTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    use FixturesTrait;

    /**
     * Description API_URL const
     *
     * @var string API_URL
     */
    private const API_URL = '/api/character/races';

    /**
     * Description testGetCollection function
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws ClientExceptionInterface
     * @throws RedirectionExceptionInterface
     * @throws ServerExceptionInterface
     * @throws TransportExceptionInterface
     * @throws DecodingExceptionInterface
     */
    public function testGetCollection(): void
    {
        $this->loadFixtures(['races']);
        /** @var ResponseInterface $response */
        $response = $this->client->request('GET', self::API_URL);

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        $this->assertResponseHeaderSame('content-type', 'application/ld+json; charset=utf-8');
        $this->assertJsonContains([
            '@context'         => '/api/contexts/Character/Race',
            '@id'              => '/api/character/races',
            '@type'            => 'hydra:Collection',
            'hydra:totalItems' => 101,
            'hydra:view'       => [
                '@id'         => '/api/character/races?page=1',
                '@type'       => 'hydra:PartialCollectionView',
                'hydra:first' => '/api/character/races?page=1',
                'hydra:last'  => '/api/character/races?page=4',
                'hydra:next'  => '/api/character/races?page=2',
            ],
        ]);
        $this->assertCount(30, $response->toArray()['hydra:member']);
        $this->assertMatchesResourceCollectionJsonSchema(Race::class);
    }

    /**
     * Description testCreate function
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws TransportExceptionInterface
     */
    public function testCreate(): void
    {
        /** @var User $users */
        $users = $this->loadFixtures(['users']);
        $this->login($users['user1']);
        $client = static::createClient();

        $client->request('POST', self::API_URL, [
            'json' => [
                'label'       => 'Race-2',
                'description' => 'bla bla bla',
                'enabled'     => false,
            ],
        ]);

        $this->assertResponseRedirects();
    }

    /**
     * Description testGet function
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws ClientExceptionInterface
     * @throws RedirectionExceptionInterface
     * @throws ServerExceptionInterface
     * @throws TransportExceptionInterface
     */
    public function testGet(): void
    {
        $this->loadFixtures(['races']);
        /** @var string $iri */
        $iri = $this->findIriBy(Race::class, ['label' => 'Race']);

        $this->client->request('GET', $iri);

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        $this->assertResponseHeaderSame('content-type', 'application/ld+json; charset=utf-8');
        $this->assertMatchesResourceItemJsonSchema(Race::class);
    }

    /**
     * Description testPut function
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws TransportExceptionInterface
     */
    public function testPut(): void
    {
        /** @var User $users */
        $users = $this->loadFixtures(['users', 'races']);
        $this->login($users['user1']);
        /** @var string $iri */
        $iri = $this->findIriBy(Race::class, ['label' => 'Race']);

        $this->client->request('PUT', $iri, [
                'json' => [
                    'enabled' => false,
                ],
            ]);

        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(403);
        $this->assertResponseHeaderSame('content-type', 'application/problem+json; charset=utf-8');
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this thread can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343674/phpunit-segmentation-fault

Comment: I've run GDB and I've this informations : `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555558c59b8 in ?? ()`